# Avoid manipulation of the userid in an kind of email confirmation hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api

This is my use case:

Our end customer sends an inquiry to our application.

The application is searching for an appropriate third party company to do the inquiry for the end customer by recieving an email with a yes/no link we want to do the job for the end customer.

Now I have to secure the yes/no feedback HttpGet endpoints with kind of a UserId.

But we have no authentication or User in our system so far. Just a customer entity with a database id.

But I can not attach a database surrogate key to the hyperlink in the email because they could replace that id with another... and click on yes button which would cause damage to the one third party company related to that id.

Then I thought of a Guid. But actually I do not want to exchange

```
the integer unique identifier
```

with

```
the Guid
```

I do not want to hand out anything from my database schema.

What would be more appropriate in my scenario?

I also want to mention that this is no email/account confirmation link scenario.

Comment: This sound like a good time to add authentication to the application.

Comment: No chance not yet! We have a big identityServer project next year march ;-)

Comment: Without some form of user authentication, I don't know how you would expect to secure anything ever.

Comment: Use a Guid instead of the Id would solve the problem, as nobody can guess the Guid and its 99,9999999% unique.

Comment: It wouldn't exactly solve the problem.  If an end user were to get a copy of the email sent to another user, then they could fake it.  Passwords = secret.  Emails = not secret.

Comment: It is very unlikely that someone from a company gets the email of another company with the "job offer". Both companies would want to avoid that ;-)

Comment: It's unlikely to get into car accident but you still want to wear your seat belt. "Appropriate" would be doing it the right way. Anyway.. if you can sell your concept to your customer with a straight face, and they cheer, clap their hands and offer a big pile of money, then by all means, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply encrypt the surrogate key with your favorite brand of encryption (ex: AES). Then decrypt the key when the user clicks the link and you should avoid passing anything to the user because you're only doing encryption/decryption on your side.

Comment: I thought about hashing the "UserId" to know wether the user tampered with the value. Because the user is allowed to see the UserId. He just should not change it.

Comment: Additionally its better just to append the generated hash to the link without the id. But then encryption seems to fit more ;-)